# Syntax Error Insert ; and } to complete statement?

Tags: android, syntax-error

I have just started to learn how to program android apps, And im a COMPLETE NOOB. 
I cant figure out how to fix this! please help! The format may look butchered... It's cause i have no clue what im doing!

```
    package com.smiggle.bmxhandbook;

     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.view.Menu;

    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.content.Intent;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


        Button button;

    public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick1(View arg0) { 

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Trick.class           
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

            }

            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub; }

    }
```

It keeps on giving me a syntax error!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) { 

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Trick.class);      
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }       

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your class had a ridiculously high amount of syntax and logical errors:

- Arbitrary `onCreate1()` method, which will never me called.
- Arbitrary `onClick()` method, even though your Activity never implemented the interface
- Your anonymous inner class' `onClick()` method was named `onClick1()`
- The statement with the `Intent` was missing a `);` at the end.
- The inner class body was missing a closing `});`
- The `addListenerOnButton()` method was missing a closing `}`
- Your entire class was missing a closing `}`

I sincerely recommend you spend a few months (or even a year) learning Java before coming to Android.

Answer (score 0):

You have this wide open

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Trick.class
```

You need to close that with a right parenthesis and and a semicolon.

Also that onClick should not have a 1 in it:

```
public void onClick1(View arg0) {
```